# hyperxmp: pdfauthor creates no /Author entry

Tags: author, metadata, hyperxmp, xmp

I recently learned of the disconnect between `pdfx` and `hyperxmp`, and have tried to transfer my document entirely over to the latter.  Everything seems to be working quite well, except that the key `pdfauthor` is appearing only the XMP data; no `/Author` field is created.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={The TITLE},%
    pdfauthor={The AUTHOR},%
}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The argument to `pdfauthor` appears in the `dc:creator` portion of the XMP data, which seems correct; but is there a way to coerce `hyperxmp` to create an `/Author` entry, as well, or to create one separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documentated on page 14 of the hyperxmp documentation. You need the key keeppdfinfo.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{%
    keeppdfinfo,
    pdftitle={The TITLE},%
    pdfauthor={The AUTHOR},%
}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect.  I didn't make the connection between the `/Author` entry and the `/Info` dictionary the documentation spoke about.  Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this problem because Adobe Acrobat would show the Author just fine (in doc info), but tools such as Chrome's PDF viewer and other open-source PDF viewers would not show the Author (it is blank). Perhaps the open-source tools are legacy and use/need the data from /Info. It's important to note (per the doc) that the hyperxmp 4.0+ version does not provide /Author in /Info to achieve compliance to the PDF/A standard.